# Can you install Linux on the Google Nest Hub?

Tags: system-installation

I got this piece of junk free with a phone purchase. I tried to sell it and got no takers - even at $20. I thought I could use it to run Amazon Prime Video while I use my desktop screen real estate to write code.... but the blasted thing won't stream anything but google properties.

So, last-ditch effort before it goes to electronics recycling: I've been unable to find anyone who has successfully installed Linux on one of these junkers, but google has thoroughly polluted the search result space - so maybe it's out there and I've just missed it?

Thanks...

Comment: I would take it back to the shop. Where I live UK/Europe, the shop has to pay for disposal.

Comment: This is an interesting question, I think the hardware design is nice. I would like to have something like this for it to work with a raspberry pi, or just flash Android onto this device.